# Delete row from DDBB through PHP

Tags: php, database, alert

I have the following table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE subjects (
  subject_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject text,
  PRIMARY KEY (subject_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I show this table in my php in the following way (index.php):

```
<table class="subjects">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3" style="border-top-left-radius: 15px; border-top-right-radius: 15px;"><h2>Asignaturas</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Asignatura </th>
        <th> Eliminar </th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects"; /*Select from table name: subjects*/
    $result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/

    if ($result->num_rows==0){

        echo '<p style="color: blue; text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">No hay asignaturas</p>';

    }else{
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "</td><td>".$row["subject"]."</td><td><a class='eliminate' onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm to delete');\" href=\"deleteSubject.php?id=".$row['subject_id']."\">X</a></td></tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

and deleteSubject.php is like this:

```
<?php
include('Conexion.php');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$subject_id = $_GET['subject_id']; // $id is defined

mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM subjects WHERE subject_id='".$subject_id."'");
mysqli_close($conn);
```

The problem I have is that it does not allow me to delete subjects when I click on the X. It shows me the confirmation alert to be able to erase but it doesn’t do anything, it just refreshes the index.php page without deleting anything.

Can somebody help me see where the error is? Thank you

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address immediately

Comment: Are you getting value in $subject_id?  try to execute query directly on database and see if its giving any error

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing the variable `id` when you request to delete, but are trying to access the variable `subject_id` in `$_GET['subject_id']`.

try `$_GET['id']` instead.

also, make sure to validate the value is a valid id and use prepared statements to increase security as you have a huge SQL injection vulnerability like someone mentioned.

Comment: Now it works! Yes, I am also aware to use prepared statements to increase security, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Error is here

```
$subject_id = $_GET['subject_id'];
```

should be

```
$subject_id = $_GET['id'];
```

You need to validate query sting before any operations on id, its necessary for stopping sql injections or XSS attack